# Java Graphics2D Transparent Rendering

Tags: java, graphics, transparency

I am making a simple 2D game in java... I am using java's Graphics2D to output to my screen. I want to be able to draw things that are partially transparent, can I do this? Or will I have to change my entire project to rendering using some other method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [`Graphics2D.setComposite(AlphaComposite)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setComposite%28java.awt.Composite%29) prior to drawing the `Image`.